# What is the best way to clearly define the types of the parameters of a function in javascript when creating a library of functions?

Tags: function, vector, three.js, prototype

Suppose I want to define a "useful" function that takes a THREE.Vector2 as well as some scaler values as inputs. What's the best syntax for defining the function if I want other people to easily understand the types of the parameters that need to be passed into the function? Sample (that doesn't work):

```
export function clipToBox(v: THREE.Vector2, boxWidth, boxHeight) {
  const clippedVector = new THREE.Vector2

  // Do some clever clipping math...

  return clippedVector
}
```

[Example of what we want users of our function to see when editing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlfoJ.png)

Comment: Have you given https://jsdoc.app/ a try?

Comment: There are several ways to do this, leading to opinion-based answers. You could try https://www.typescriptlang.org/